# Key-value stores for medium to large values

Tags: image, storage, key-value, key-value-store

We have a system that stores (single-digit) millions of images, varying in size from 8KB to 500KB, median around 15KB, average 30KB. The total data set is currently around 100GB. We want to access the image based upon a hash of the image (this *can* be changed, but it needs to be computable from the image for the purpose of checking whether an image is already in the data store efficiently — images are processed such that two images are pixel-for-pixel identical iff they are byte-for-byte identical). Persistence is (obviously) important.

At the moment we store them all as files within a directory — the listing of the directory are cached by the kernel, and actual file-reads are done as needed. As I understand it, the main advantage of key-value stores (versus using a filesystem as one) is reading smaller values, as the whole page can be cached, instead of just a single value. All the access currently comes from the web server (on an intranet) on the same server as the data, though we may move to checking whether keys exist from remote machines (mostly connected through 10GbE).

There isn't any particular reason to change it, though with other major parts of the system changing, it seems worthwhile to re-consider the current approach.

Given a workload whose reading is primarily (single) reads in insertion order and random (though quite possibly repeated) accesses to arbitrary keys, in addition to frequent writes (something of the order of magnitude 1:10 write:read), is there likely to be much advantage to moving to a key-value store from the filesystem?

Comment: It depends on your current system.  If it is monolithic (single machine serving requests from a single storage location) you may see a benefit by adding multiple nodes, and storing copies of the data closer to the clients that are consuming it.  To frame an answer, you would have to detail the composition of your current system and where your current bottlenecks are that need to be remedied.

Comment: 2KB file are so completly different that 10MB files w.r.t. the meta data overhead/directory overheads. Reading a 2KB file from disk is easier meta data limited and seek limited and a 10 MB files where the major time is the actual streaming. Can you say a bit more about the file size distribution? Are small files the norm or medium files?

Comment: check out Microsoft Sharepoint for this kind of job, it might meet your needs. In this case, there's no need to reinvent the wheel

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Depending on

- the number of files
- how you structure them on the FS
- which FS you're using
- what kind of storage you're using

you may end up running out of inodes, or may have slow times accessing the files again (e.g. if you put too many entries in a single directory).

You also have to put a bit of care in accessing the files (and/or creating directories) atomically while a KV store will usually take care of that for you.

I had problems with all these things  in the past with fs-as-key-value-store approaches :) .

But It can be done, see for example [Bigdis](https://github.com/antirez/Bigdis) which is an implementation of the redis KV protocol as files-on-disk, from the redis author himself, but you have to be a bit careful with your ops.

Depending on your problem you may find [MogileFS](http://danga.com/mogilefs/) or straight cloudy S3 to be better solutions.

Answer (score 15):

> **Summary:**   For your requirements of Data Integrity, Persistence, Size & Speed I recommend **Redis**.
>
> A nice intro presentation can be seen here:
>   https://simonwillison.net/static/2010/redis-tutorial/

*n.b. More info would help but based on what you've given + what I know, here are some of the main players:*

**Memcached:**
https://memcached.org/
A free, open source, high-performance, distributed memory object caching system, good for speeding up dynamic web applications.
**+** good for web applications, free, open source.
**-** if the server goes down (memcached process failure or system reboot) all sessions are lost. Performance limitations at the higher (commercial usage) levels.

**Redis:**
https://redis.io/
Similar to memcached but with data persistence, supports multiple value types, counters with atomic increment/decrement and built-in key expiration.
**+** saves data to disk so never lost, very simple, speed, flexibility (keys can contain strings, hashes, lists, sets and sorted sets), sharding, maintained by vmware rather than an individual.
**-** limited clustering.

**LevelDB:**
https://google-opensource.blogspot.com/2011/07/leveldb-fast-persistent-key-value-store.html
A fast key-value storage engine written at Google that maps string keys to string values.
**+** Google.
**-** ?possible with Google + ;)

**TokoyoCabinet:**
https://fallabs.com/tokyocabinet/
Includes support for locking, ACID transactions, a binary array data type.
+ Speed and efficiency.
- Less known in some areas, e.g. US

**Project Voldemort:**
https://project-voldemort.com/
An advanced key-value store, written in Java. Provides multi-version concurrency control (MVCC) for updates. Updates to replicas are done asynchronously, so it does not guarantee consistent data.
**+** Functionality
**-** Conistency

**MongoDB:**
https://www.mongodb.org/
A scalable, high-performance, open source, document-oriented database. Written in C++  Features Replication & High Availability with mirrors across LANs and WANs and Auto-Sharding.  Popular in the Ruby on Rails community.
**+** Easy installation, good documentation, support.
**-** Relatively new.

**Couch:**
http://www.couchdb.org/
Similar to Mongo, aimed at document databases.
**+** replication, advanced queries.
**-** clustering, disk space management.

**Cassandra:**
https://cassandra.apache.org/
Apache Cassandra is fault-tolerant and decentralized and is used at Netflix, Twitter and Reddit, among others.
**+** Cluster and replication.
**-** More setup knowledge needed.

I can't provide all the references, due to lack of time but hope this at least helps.

Answer (score 2):

You provide too little information to give a specific answer - thus just some aspects relevant to what you describe:

- data integrity
  This can be anything - i.e. unauthorized data change should be prohibited and/or at least any such incident sould be detected... OR it can be just something in the area of "RAID and/or backup...".
- "identical images"
  image files contain several metadata fields/areas... your method leads to seeing two pixel-by-pixel-identical images as different if one has metadata and the other not (or some metadata field differs)... is that what you want ?
  Another aspect in this area is file format (PNG versus BMP versus JPEG etc.) and compression... same image and different format and/or compression algorithms (even lossless ones like ZIP versus LZW, worse with JPEG etc.) can lead to categorize the same image as different - is that what you want ?
- "hundreds of thousands of images" and "2 KB - 10 MB"
  that doesn't say much... i.e. what is the median versus average image/file size ?
- access
  Is the access to those files/images distributed (like in a CDN) ? Or is it LAN-based ?

There are dozens of other aspects relevant to what you describe...

Without any further and really specific information I would consider any statistics/benchmark/recommendation a lucky shot at best.

Possible solutions include for example distributed system (can be filesystem-/memory-/DB-based) and/or storage based on SSD and/or RAID and/or SAN etc.

The "KeyValueStore" point you are interested in could be relevant but in most cases handling this amount of images I came across such a store wouldn't add any unique feature (and in some cases even hurt).

Comment: Data-integrity was really a far too vague, I must agree: really the only thing I'm concerned about is that the data got out of the key-value store is the same as what was put in. Identical images were mentioned in the question (they are processed so that they are pixel-for-pixel identical they are byte-for-byte identical). Otherwise, the question now addresses the rest.

Comment: @gsnedders thanks for the additonal info... even with millions of images I don't see how a KeyValueStore would bring any benefit... what is it you expect spcifically of a KeyValueStore ?

Answer (score 1):

If your data is under 1TB you arguably do not need a high-availability NoSQL database, and most NoSQL databases require that data is kept is RAM. May I suggest using a bog-standard relational DB and making a table with hash as primary key and a blob with your data? You'd be surprised how well it performs, and you don't need to worry about running out of inodes.

If your data is textual / compressible a relational database is even better. In my experience few NoSQL databases will compress data for you, you have to do it at the client side. But MySQL/MariaDB offer transparent compression.

Another option is RocksDB. For some use-cases, it's very good for disk space because it supports zstd compression with a custom dictionary.